# Manipulating JSON data with PHP

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json, post

Scenario: Playing an online game, have an javascript file that allows me to port data to a PHP on a server using POST/json.  I have to enter the path of my server into my client PC for this to work.  I am getting a confirmation that connection is fine.

The PHP only recognises source from the website I am playing on, and I can see data transferring to the site in my developer console.  The data being POSTed is in the following format:
I can see the data coming in an array looking at the console:

```
Request URL: //xxxxxx.xxxx/aix/server_api.php Request Method:POST Status Code:200 OK Request Headersview source Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01 Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3 Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6 Connection:keep-alive Content-Length:65236 Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 Host:sd.fast-page.org Origin:http://xx.yyy.com Referer:http://xxx.yyy.com/232/index.aspx User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/25.0.1364.160 Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22 Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded alliance[id]:118 alliance[name]:DS alliance[members]:12 alliance[score]:982078 data_type:city data[0][id]:12517457 data[0][owner_id]:1538 data[0][owner]:MM1 data[0][coords]:'081:191 data[0][name]:C31 4Chief data[0][score]:11020 data[0][city_type]:castle data[0][location]:land data[1][id]:12517458 data[1][owner_id]:1538 data[1][owner]:MM1 data[1][coords]:'082:191 data[1][name]:C31 5Redrum data[1][score]:10596 data[1][city_type]:castle data[1][location]:water data[2][id]:12386381 data[2][owner_id]:1538 data[2][owner]:MM1 data[2][coords]:'077:189 data[2][name]:C31 1Home data[2][score]:10460 data[2][city_type]:castle data[2][location]:land data[3][id]:12320847 data[3][owner_id]:1538 data[3][owner]:MM1 data[3][coords]:'079:188 data[3][name]:C31 6North data[3][score]:10182 data[3][city_type]:castle data[3][location]:land data[4][id]:12386382 data[4][owner_id]:1538 data[4][owner]:MM1 data[4][coords]:'078:189 data[4][name]:C31 3Back data[4][score]:10108 data[4][city_type]:castle data[4][location]:land data[5][id]:12517453 data[5][owner_id]:1538 data[5][owner]:MM1 data[5][coords]:'077:191 data[5][name]:C31 2Second data[5][score]:9968 data[5][city_type]:castle data[5][location]:land data[6][id]:12714060 data[6][owner_id]:1538 data[6][owner]:MM1 data[6][coords]:'076:194 data[6][name]:C31 MacoHub data[6][score]:9692 data[6][city_type]:castle data[6][location]:land data[7][id]:12517460 data[7][owner_id]:1538 data[7][owner]:MM1 data[7][coords]:'084:191 data[7][name]:C31 Tango data[7][score]:9163 data[7][city_type]:castle data[7][location]:land data[8][id]:12582993 data[8][owner_id]:1538 data[8][owner]:MM1 data[8][coords]:'081:192 data[8][name]:C31 Spring data[8][score]:8864 data[8][city_type]:castle data[8][location]:land data[9][id]:12517454 data[9][owner_id]:1538 data[9][owner]:MM1 data[9][coords]:'078:191 data[9][name]:C31 Pally data[9][score]:8816 data[9][city_type]:castle data[9][location]:land data[10][id]:12779603 data[10][owner_id]:1538
[and so on and so forth.....have masked the rest but this is the format
Response Headersview source Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS Access-Control-Allow-Origin: //xxx.yyy Access-Control-Max-Age:1000 Cache-Control:no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, no-transform Connection:keep-alive Content-Encoding:gzip Content-Length:70 Content-Type:application/json Date:Fri, 29 Mar 2013 18:08:14 GMT Expires:Fri, 29 Mar 2013 18:08:14 GMT Pragma:no-cache Server:Apache Vary:Accept-Encoding X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.0alpha5
```

Now what I see above is the output to the console on my PC when I trigger the client app.

The PHP is as follows:

```
$m = false;
if(preg_match('/http\:\/\/game url/',$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'],$m))
    { $m = $m[1]; }

if(empty($m)) { die('Invalid Origin.'); }

if(!empty($_POST['data_type']))
{
    $sender     = $_POST['sender'];
    $alliance   = $_POST['alliance'];
    $request    = $_POST['data_type'];
    $data       = $_POST['data'];

    // Response to Alliance Info Exporter
    $json       = array(
        'message'   => 'recieved.',
        'data'      => array(),
        'error'     => false
    );

    // handle data types
    switch($request)
    {
        case 'connection_test': $json['message'] = 'Welcome to our server. Your are connected!'; break;
        case 'member'   : /* Code for member request */         break;
        case 'city'     : /* Code for city request */           break;
        case 'support'  : /* Code for support request */        break;
        default         :  $json['message'] = 'Nothing Done.';  break;
    }

    // set headers for API
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    // Respond
    die(json_encode($json));
}
die('No Access.');
```

I have two or three problems here

1. I can't seem to manipulate the data that the PHP is getting at all
2. Whenever I try to add any arguments to the case statement just to even see if I can parse  the data somehow then the api stops responding to my client

For example, at the city switch I just tried to output the data to a file just  to confirm it was coming through because my browser console gives me a POST success code (http 200)

This is the code I used:

```
$f = fopen("city.txt", "w");
fwrite($f, $_POST);
fclose($f);
```

I tried it in the main part of my PHP, tried it at the city case switch (that is the type of query I am executing first), and I tried with other defined types like $data, etc. Nothing writes.

What am I doing wrong?

Secondly my endstate is to post this to a SQL server, how would I do that?

Comment: When you say nothing writes, do you mean you get an empty file?  Or the file doesn't even show up?

When you say "I can't seem to manipulate the data that the PHP is getting at all", what are you trying to manipulate?

It would be helpful to have examples of the actual data in $_POST['data_type'] and $_POST['data'].

Also, are you on Windows, Mac, Linux?

Comment: I get an empty file, all this code is on a local dev environment which is Linux/Apache based